# 0% jacoco coverage on jenkins. html file is fine, but .exec is broken?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-plugins, jacoco, gradle-plugin

The report is fine on local, when opening the html file, but on jenkins it looks like this:

[image: jacoco coverage on jenkins]

if i open the html file on jenkins it looks fine aswell, but the exec file it uses is broken for some reason.

My jenkins config looks like this:

[image: jenkins config]

and in gradle:

[image: gradle config]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you run a local build and look at where the `*.exec` files and `*.class` files are built to. I think your Jenkins config will be something like

Path to exec files: `**/build/jacoco/*.exec`

Path to classes directories: `**/build/classes/java/main`

Comment: Was the class directories. Thank you, life saver!